# LibGDX Camera DragnDrop and Actors

Tags: drag-and-drop, camera, libgdx, drag, actor

I have implemented camera dragging so that the player can move around the scene freely by just dragging.

This is my approach:

```
stage.addListener(new DragListener() {
       public void touchDragged (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
           camera.position.set(x,y, 0);
           camera.update();
       }

    });
```

This works for bodies (Box2d) but images stay still where they are. Is there a way to make images to where the bodies are or make them move according to camera position? These images are Actors because I need them to be touchable and draggable too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but it sounds like you're in the same situation as I was. I was not able to get the Actors to stay in one spot, however, I did find that using Sprites worked just as well as Actors for me, and they would also stay in one spot assuming you have your cameras set up correctly